# Why can't React Native (RN) convert the main.bundle.js to native code to avoid the RN Bridge between VM & Native Modules

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was wondering why do we need the RN Bridge in the React Native engine which connects the Javascript VM (JavascriptCore) with the Native Modules. This bridge and message passing setup only slows down the app speed and creates a bottleneck. Why can't the package bundler spawned by React Native CLI, instead of just bundling javascript codes to main.bundle.js, also convert it to native code? one reason I've heard is coz javascript is not strongly typed, but this reason doesn't seem unsolvable. Any other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed transpiling javascript into native code will provide tremendous performance improvements however it is not an easy thing to do at all. That being said, there are a lot of reasons why transpilation from one language to another is hard, and this is especially true if we consider the host language to be javascript and the target language to be java or something similar like C# and objective c.

Javascript is extremely different from these languages, many of the ideas are hard to map into a one to one, and the mindset is completely different.

Another thing that is special about javascript, and that makes it hard to transpile it to another language, is that javascript can never be a versioned language, and that since its the language of the web it has to always support backward compatibility. This means if a tool were to transpile from javascript to another language, this tool needs to support everything that javascript supports - one might argue that a tool might support only a recent subset of javascript, something like es6, however this is dangerous for two reasons, one it will be hard to define this subset exactly since a lot of es6 features are working by polyfills from es5, and two that this means that this tool wont be able to support all the javascript ecosystem.

here are some of details about some challenging parts of javascript to be transpiled into a language like java:

- javascript is a dynamic language, not only there are no restrictions on types, but javascript do an extremely complex type coercing techniques in different operations under different conditions

```
consider this
true + 1 === 1 + '1' // false
true + 1 === 1 + +1 // true
```

- Javascript introduced modules system only recently (starting from es6) this practically means that any program is  one huge chunk of code, where variables live through out the entire program.
- Javascript inheritance system (the Prototypal Inheritance system) is extremely different from classical inheritance systems in these languages, for example in javascript at runtime you can change the the class of an object, at the same time in runtime you can also change the methods of a class.

Now on top of all the technical challenges, notice that there is a product wise decision here, in making RN like this. This enabled RN to go to market faster, and not be tied to certain native language, this means its much more easier this way to support new environments by just transpiling ui controls to the native ui of that environment, and keeping javascript as it is. And on top of that if tomorrow, someone find a way to transpile javascript to java, this tool can be easily integrated into RN pipeline, without affecting the other components and supported environments of RN.